# Away3d building an irregular Polygon as a plane

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, away3d

I have a sprite which helps the user draw a custom shape? i want to tile the surface how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use EarCutting for Triangulation.
- Convert your 2D points to 3D  points for(Away3D).
- Use the points to build custom Mesh.
- Bingo!!

**> The tricky part is to calculate the UV for the texture**